# I have two React components fetching from a Flask App. One works but one doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, axios

```
import './Checklist.css'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";

const fetchData = (hook) => {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:5000/shopping")
      .then((response) => hook(response.data.shoppingList));
  }

function Checklist() {
    const [shoppingList, setShoppingList] = useState();
        useEffect(() => {
                fetchData(setShoppingList)
              }, []);
    
        return (
            <div className='checklist-div'>
                <header>Shopping List</header>
                <div className='shopping-div'>
                    {shoppingList.map((entry, index) => {
                        if (index % 3) {
                            return (
                                <div className="form-check form-switch" key={index}>
                                    <input className="form-check-input" disabled id={`${entry}-input`} type="checkbox" />
                                    <label className="form-check-label" >{entry}</label>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        return (
                            <div className="form-check form-switch" key={index}>
                                <input className="form-check-input" id={`${entry}-input`} type="checkbox" />
                                <label className="form-check-label" >{entry}</label>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    )};
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default Checklist;
```

Checklist is grabbing a json object containing an array from the server but gives a 'Can't perform a React state update on a component that hasn't mounted yet'. I've checked and the route used does give the array when accessed directly but my handling of the response in the code is causing problems

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import './ReactLogo.css'
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const fetchData = (hook) => {
        return axios.get("http://localhost:5000/")
          .then((response) => hook(response.data.greeting));
      }
    
        function ReactLogo() {
          const [heartbeat, setHeartbeat] = useState();
          fetchData(setHeartbeat);
        
          return (
            <div className="react-logo-div">
                <img src={logo} className="react-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>
                  Edit <code>src/ReactLogo.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                  className="react-logo-link"
                  href="https://reactjs.org"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                  Learn Unit Tests
                </a>
                <p>
                  {heartbeat}
                </p>
            </div>
          );
        }
    
        export default ReactLogo;
```

I use the same implementation for reactLogo.js and it works fine just grabbing a JSON string object

Comment: Usually you do not want to pass state setter functions outside of your component, you should prefer awaiting the response from your API and .then() set the state from inside your component. Said that, the only difference I see is that in your first component you are calling the API from inside a useState and the Logo component is calling the API directly. Also, I believe you should add dependencies to your useEffect and in particular the one dependency is setShoppingList

Comment: Good advice on clean up. Was a little desperate so hadn't cleaned up some attempts.